# How to use Perl to list certain pattern from multiple XML files

Tags: xml, regex, perl, automation

I want to create list of all filenames with *.ini extension mentioned in content of certain set of XML files in single folder.
They all include full path, but I need only **Filename.ini**

Basically it means to open all xml files, read it, find all filenames with *.ini ext and print it.

I was thinking about following perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
@files = <P:\TeamMembers\rsacek\_INI\*>;
foreach my $file (@fnames) {
    chomp $file;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
        push @files, /[">](.*\.ini)["<]/ig;
     }
}
print "File names found: @files\n";
```

Any ideas? I have about 30k files to read.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you run the code? Does it work?

Comment: Hints: `use strict; use warnings;`. Use forwards slashes as path separator, backslashes introduce escape sequences. `@fnames` is empty. The glob operator does not append newlines to the filenames. Use non-greedy match `.*?` or be more specific with matched characters: `[^"<]+`.

Comment: I am lost here. How should I define '@fnames', append newlines and tweak the regex?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using either the `File::Find` or `File::Find::Rule` module amongst an `XML Parser` which handles all messy recursion. Why reinvent the wheel?

Using `File::Find`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @found;
find(\&wanted, 'P:/TeamMembers/rsacek/_INI');

foreach ( @found ) {
   print "$_\n";
}

sub wanted {
   return unless -f;
   open my $fh, '<', $File::Find::name or warn "failed $!" and return;
   while (<$fh>) {
      push @found, $1 if /[">](.*?\.ini)["<]/ig;
   }
   close $fh;
}
```

But perhaps for an alternative approach, this should work.

I use `grep` (which is mainly a function for list filtering) for items returned that are not files. `map` is being used to grab the full path rather then keep looping and looking for it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = 'P:/TeamMembers/rsacek/_INI';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "failed opening '$dir' $!";

my @found;
foreach my $f ( map { "$dir/$_" } grep { -f "$dir/$_" } readdir $dh ) {
   open my $fh, '<', $f or die "failed opening '$f' $!";
   while ( <$fh> ) {
       push @found, $1 if /[">](.*?\.ini)["<]/ig;
   } 
   close $fh;
}
closedir $dh;

foreach ( @found ) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working, but this regex gives me no result. However it worked with the above `/[">](.*\.ini)["<]/ig`.

Comment: However, I still get all results on single line. How to put each occurrence on a new line?

Answer (score 1):

To get just the filename portion, you could use "basename". Example:

```
use File::Basename;
$album_name = basename($pwd);
```